# Nilsimsa hash / digest in Java?

Tags: java, digest

I'm looking for a Nilsimsa or some other LSH function implementation in Java, for detecting similar strings in a stream  of incoming strings.

Doesn't seem reasonable that there is no public implementation of it, and I hate re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a port of the Python Nilsimsa code [here](http://github.com/weblyzard/nilsimsa).

Answer (score 1):

you can find One LSH implementation in [TarsosLSH](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosLSH).